# How to automatically set CreatedOn fields with Entity Framework on saved entity and its child properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

Whenever I call `databaseContext.SaveChanges()`, before data is saved by Entity Framework, I need all objects and their child classes to have the `CreatedOn` field populated with `DateTime.Now()`.

Details: I have a `BaseEntity` class that all entities inherit from:

```
 public class BaseEntity
 {
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id{ get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
 }
```

Whenever an entity that inherits from `BaseEntity` above is saved, the `CreatedOn` property gets assigned `DateTime.Now`.

Here is a base repository that does it:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
     ....

     public virtual bool SaveChanges(TEntity entity)
     {            
         if (entity.CreatedOn == DateTime.MinValue)
             entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
         else
             entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;

         return _databaseContext.SaveChanges() > 0;           
     }
}
```

This works well but the problem is that only object's itself `CreatedOn` property gets updated. Any child classes there may be **do not** get updated.

How can I change my logic in the `SaveChanges()` method to update all child classes and set their `CreatedOn` dates as well?

I'll provide an example to make this more clear: imagine an instance of a `User` object below added to the `dbContext` with a new `Profile`, as well as new `Role` class instances assigned and then `SaveChanges()` is called:

```
public class User: BaseEntity
{
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public UserRole Role { get; set; }
        public ProfileDetails Profile { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

What's the best way to make sure that `CreatedOn` date gets assigned for child  `user.Role`, as well as `user.Profile` objects (both classes also inherit from `BaseEntity`)? I thought of using Reflection to check child object properties for `CreatedOn` fields but all the looping doesn't feel right. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you should override the `SaveChanges` method in your own DB context class and use the EF change tracker to get all newly created objects, and then set their `CreatedOn`  fields accordingly.

Something along the lines of this:

```
public class DbContextBase : DbContext 
{
    public override int SaveChanges() 
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        // get all the entities in the change tracker - this could be optimized
        // to fetch only the entities with "State == added" if that's the only 
        // case you want to handle
        IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry<BaseEntity>> entities = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>();

        // handle newly added entities
        foreach (DbEntityEntry<BaseEntity> entity in entities.Where(e => (e.State == EntityState.Added)) 
        {
            // set the CreatedOn field to the current date&time
            entity.Entity.CreatedOn = currentDateTime;
        }

        // to the actual saving of the data
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Of course you could improve on this:

- also handle the entities with `e.State == EntityState.Modified` and set a `ModifiedOn` field in this case
- add some custom exception handling to handle common problem cases
- so much more - the sky and your imagination is the limit!

Comment: This looks like a good solution, except that ChangeTracker is part of EF Core? It's not part of Entity Framework 6.

Comment: @InspiredBy: this is an **EF 6** solution that I've had in production for many months - this is **NOT** EF Core exclusively - definitely not. See [EF Change Tracker (EF 6 Tutorials)](https://entityframework.net/change-tracker) and [MS Docs on DbContext.ChangeTracker property (EF 6.2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: Thank you. The solution worked once I modified the syntax: Based on [DBChangeTracker Class docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)  that state that "The ChangeTracker method of DbContext to provide access to features of the context...". I swapped `ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()` to `databaseContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()` and then it worked like a charm. I'm very grateful. Thank you.
Could maybe update your answer and I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: @InspiredBy: since this method is on a `DbContext` descendant class, you *should* be able to use the code I provided **as-is** - I have, for many many months. Not really sure why you needed to add a `databaseContext.ChangeTracker` .....

Comment: @InspiredBy: strange .... is this project of yours a .NET Core project??  `ChangeTracker` is a **property** on the `DbContext` class - should definitely be available. Can you try using `this.ChangeTracker` maybe??

Comment: Accepted as this is technically the right solution. Hopefully, these comments will be helpful to future generations.

Answer (score 1):

With EF Core 7 you can use [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors).

```
public sealed class UpdateEntityLifetimeInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
       DbContext? dbContext = eventData.Context;
       if (dbContext is null)
       {
           return await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
       }

       var entities = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>();

       foreach (var entity in entities)
       {
           if (entity.CreatedOn == DateTime.MinValue)
               entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
           else
               entity.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
       }

       return await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```